# Change CSS stles from view in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

Sorry if this is an obvious question, I am new to django and still learning.
I am creating a website that contains 6 images in total. The images in the website should remain invisible until its image id is passed from views.py.

I have a template index.html page and view that loads when this url is accessed localhost/imageid

What I need now is to make the image visible whenever its url is access. So for instance if a user goes to localhost/1. QR code 1 should be made visible. I am also storing the state of all access images. So if the user accesses the website again and goes to localhost/2 it should make image 1 and 2 visible. I am using sessions to store the state. I just need a way of making the images visible.

Thankyouuuu

Answer (score 0):

Depends so a basic view would be:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'my_html.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['img_id'] = self.kwargs.get('pk')  # this is whatever the variable is named in the URL.
        return context
```

html would be something like this.:

```
<body>
    {%if img_id == 1 %}
        <img src="image1path">
    {%elif img_id == 2 %}
        <img src="image2path">
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

A better way would be to store the images in a database and get the image paths from a model, then you would get that in the context and reference it in the template instead of having if statements.